# javascript substr window.location.href

Tags: javascript

this is a very beginner question but I don't know javascript, I only wants implement a snipplet I found googling around.

The original code is:

```
var langcodes=["it", "es"];
var langCode = navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage;
var lang = langCode.toLowerCase(); 
lang = lang.substr(0,2); 
var dest = window.location.href; 
for (i=langcodes.length-1;i >= 0; i--){
    if (lang==langcodes[i]){
        dest = dest.substr(0,dest.lastIndexOf('.')) + '-' + lang.substr(0,2) + dest.substr(dest.lastIndexOf('.'));
        window.location.replace ?window.location.replace(dest) :window.location=dest;
    }
}
```

if my browser language is it_IT, will replace

```
    http://www.mysite.com/test.html
```

to

```
    http://www.mysite.com/test-it.html
```

i'd like the new url was:

```
    http://www.mysite.com/it/test.html
```

I tried several ways with no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Max

Comment: I'd like to mention that the common way is to do that server-side. Each browser sends it's preferred languages in a simple header: `Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,lt;q=0.4` which you can parse and use to determine the language of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
 dest = dest.substr(0,dest.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/' + lang.substr(0,2) + dest.substr(dest.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if (lang==langcodes[i]){
    dest = dest.substr(0,dest.lastIndexOf('/') +1) + lang.substr(0,2) + dest.substr(dest.lastIndexOf('/'));
    window.location.replace ?window.location.replace(dest) :window.location=dest;
}
```

ok, tested on www.google.it and it woked (output www.google.it/it/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var langcodes=["it", "es"];
var langCode = navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage;
var lang = langCode.toLowerCase(); 
lang = lang.substr(0,2); 
var dest = window.location.href;

dest = dest.substr(0,dest.lastIndexOf('.')) + '-' + lang + dest.substr(dest.lastIndexOf('.'));
window.location = dest;
```